# express api select from MySQL to js variable gets undefined - promise doesn't return value

Tags: javascript, express

hi I want to assign the result of  MYSQL query to JS variable to use serval times but get back an empty array what is the problem?
my code

```
app.get('/api/get/db',async(req,res)=>{

async function test() {
new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  con.query("SELECT * FROM `temp`",(err,result)=>{
   resolve(result)
  })
 })
}
data =await test()

res.status(200).json({data})
})
```

I tried to return but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.get('/api/get/db',async(req,res)=>{

async function test() {
//here you have to add **return** keyword
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  con.query("SELECT * FROM `temp`",(err,result)=>{
   resolve(result)
  })
 })
}
data =await test()

res.status(200).json({data})
})
```

you have to add **return** keyword before promise object to return